# How to get Readyboost cache size?

Tags: c#, caching

I wrote a C# console application that reads Readyboost data from performance counters.

My problem is that Readyboost is reporting incorrect cache size. For example it reports "Total cache size bytes: 1.157366E+08" when readyboost pendrive is not connected to the computer.

This is My code and the output of the application. What I'm doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory pc;

    try
    {
        pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("ReadyBoost Cache");
        foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in pc.GetCounters())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", counter.CounterName, counter.NextValue());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
Bytes cached: 3.737436E+08
Cache space used: 1.06779E+08
Compression Ratio: 0
Total cache size bytes: 1.157366E+08
Cache reads/sec: 0
Cache read bytes/sec: 0
Skipped reads/sec: 0
Skipped read bytes/sec: 0
Total reads/sec: 0
Total read bytes/sec: 0
```